# Deriving an inequality for a set of functions that have equi-Lipschitz first derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions, equicontinuity

let $ F =\{ F_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable real valued functions such that the sequence $  F' =\{  F'_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equi-Lipschitz , i.e. there exist a real constant $L$ such that for all $x_1,x_2$

$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \le L | x_1 - x_2 | $$

for all $f \in   F'$.

Then is it true that 
$$F_{t+1} (x_1) - F_t(x_2) \le  F'_t(x_1) (x_2 -x_1) + \frac{1}{2} L ( x_2 - x_1)^2 $$
for all $t$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $F_t(x)=t$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Then $F'_t\equiv0$ fot all $t\in\Bbb N$ and $L=0$, but $F_{t+1}(x_1)-F_t(x_2)=1$ for all $t\in\Bbb N$ and all $x_i,x_2\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you! Obviously! how dumb of me, would some hypothesis on the way the functions in the sequence change make it true? or at-least approximately true?

Comment: Some condition on the differences $F_{t+1}-F_t$ is needed.

Comment: I'll write another question, thanks again!